# Using density argument of Schwartz functions in $L^2$ to show an operator is symmetric

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

The position operator $X$ is defined as multiplication by $x$, i.e.
$$(X\psi)(x):=x\psi(x).$$

We take the domain $D(X)\subset L^2(\mathbb R)$ for $X$, which we can take

$$D(X):=\{\psi \in L^2(\mathbb R), \int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2 |\psi(x)|^2 dx<\infty\}.$$

The momentum operator is defined as $$(P\psi)(x)=-i \nabla \psi(x),$$ and $$D(P):=\{\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}), \frac{d}{dx}\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})\}.$$

Finally, given an external potential $V: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, the corresponding multiplication is given by the map
$$V:D(V)\subset L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R}), \; (V\psi)(x):=V(x)\psi(x).$$ We take $$D(V):= \{\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}), V\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})\}.$$

From this we have the Hamiltonian operator $H\psi(x,t):= -\Delta\psi(x,t) + V(x)\psi(x,t).$

A **densely-defined operator** on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a pair $(A,D(A))$ where the domain $D(A)$ is a dense linear subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $A:D(A)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a linear map.

We say that a densely-defined linear operator $A$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is symmetric if for all $f,g \in D(A),$ we have
$$\langle Af, g\rangle = \langle f, Ag \rangle.$$

I am trying to prove that the operators $X,P, H$ are symmetric.

For this, I have shown that $\langle Af, g\rangle = \langle f,Ag \rangle$
for $A=X,P,H$ when $f,g$ are Schwartz functions.

Now I am trying to use the density argument to generalize this to all functions in the domain of the operators. However, I have several problems.

First, given $f_n \to f, g_n \to g$ in $L^2$, how can I show that $\lim_n \langle Af_n, g_n \rangle= \langle Af, g\rangle$?

Next, is it true that if $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$ then $Af_n \to Af$ in $L^2$ as well for each of these operators? I am not sure why this holds, but if it doesn't then it doesn't seem like I can use the above density argument, so I don't know how to prove these results.

I would greatly appreciate some help.

**Edit.**

So I believe this isn't a straightforward application of the density argument. But restricted in the calculations.

For $P$, we have
$$\langle Pf,g\rangle = \int \overline{-i \frac{d}{dx}f(x)}g(x)dx = i\int \overline{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)}g(x)dx.$$
And I need to move the derivative over to $g$, and to do this I need integration by parts which gives
$$=-i\int \overline{f(x)} \frac{dg(x)}{dx} dx+i\overline{f(x)} \frac{d}{dx}g(x)|_{-\infty}^\infty.$$ And to get rid of the boundary terms I need to take $f,g \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$.

Similarly, for the operator $V$, we have
$$\langle Hf,g\rangle = \int \overline{(-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)+V(x)f(x))} g(x)dx = \int -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\overline{f(x)}g(x)+V(x)\overline{f(x)}g(x)dx.$$

Now because $V$ is real valued, and we assume $Vf, Vg$ are in $L^2$, the right integral just becomes $\int \overline{f(x)}V(x)g(x)dx$, which is of the form we need for $Hg$.

But the first integral again needs integration by parts and to chage it to $\int -\overline{f(x)}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}g(x)dx$ we need the boundary terms to vanish.

So I believe we only need the density argument for establishing the integral identity $$ \int \frac{d}{dx}\overline{f(x)}g(x)dx = -\int \overline{f(x)}\frac{d}{dx}g(x)dx$$ and $$\int \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\overline{f(x)}g(x)dx=\int \overline{f(x)}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}g(x)dx.$$

And for these functions $f,g$ they belong to the domain $\{\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}), \frac{d}{dx}\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})\}$ and $\{\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R}), \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})\}$ for the domains of $P$ and $H$, respectively. And the Schwartz class of functions $\mathcal{S}$ belongs to these domains, and is a dense subspace of $L^2$.

But to use a density argument, for example for the first integral, we have $$|\int \nabla \overline{f_n}g_n - \nabla \overline{f}g| \\ = |\int \nabla \overline{f_n}(g_n-g) + g(\nabla \overline{f_n} - \nabla \overline{f})| \le \Vert \nabla \overline{f_n}\Vert_L^2 \Vert g_n - g\Vert_L^2 + \Vert g\Vert_L^2 \Vert \nabla \overline{f_n} - \nabla \overline{f}\Vert_L^2. $$

But here to deal with the convergence of the derivative, I had to use the $H^2$ norm. I know that $H^2$ is a dense subspace of $L^2$, but I don't know how to pass from $H^2$ functions to the functions in the domain of the operators. How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: Don't you not want to consider $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$? We know that these operators are not defined on the whole of $L^2$, hence restricting ourselves to their dense domains. Extending these operators in a meaningful way to the entire space requires a rigged Hilbert space.

Comment: @whpowell96 Yes Schwartz functions $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$. Did you interpret me as saying $f_n \to f$ pointwise?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear. I meant to say, when you consider $f_n\to f$, are you saying that $f_n$ are Schwartz and $f$ is in $D(A)$? Or are you saying that $f\in L^2$? Because $Af$ is not defined in general for $f\in L^2$

Comment: @whpowell96 oh yes $f,g$ are assumed to be in $D(A)$.

Comment: You cannot use density arguments without knowing things about your operators. You can have operators be symmetric on a dense subspace of their domain, but the operator itself is not symmetric (but know that these kinds of operators, while they exist, do not commonly appear "in nature", nor are they very useful). If the operator is closed you could possibly apply some continuity argument, but symmetry is usually much easier to check than closedness.

Comment: A detailed explanation of these operators and the relevant function spaces in QM is given in chapter 3 of *quantum Mechanics in Rigged Hilbert Space language* by de Madrid

Comment: @s.harp Yes you are right I have realized I only need a density argument for a particular integral identity. I have added my argument above. Could you check if this argument should work?

Comment: For $P$, the result follows from the density of Schwartz functions in $H^n$, for $X$ it follows similarly by taking the Fourier transform, but in general for $H$, such a result depends on the potential.

Comment: @LL3.14 How does the result follow from the density of Schwartz functions in $H^n$ when we are considering as domain the space of $L^2$ functions whose derivative is also in $L^2$? Also for $H$, potential doesn't matter, because I am only applying a density argument to the set of $L^2$ functions whose laplacian is also in $L^2$ and just using it for the integral identity of moving the laplacian as I stated in the second to last paragraph.

Comment: $f\in H^n$ means that $f$ and its first $n$ weak derivatives are $L^2$. The domain are are referring to is a subspace of $H^n$.

Comment: $H^1(\Bbb R)$ is exactly the functions of $L^2$ with gradient in $L^2$. I do not see why you can assume $f,g\in D(V)$ if you only know $f,g\in D(H)$? This should be the most difficult density argument since normally, everything is symmetric between difficulties for multiplication operators and differential operators since you can pass from one class to the other by Fourier transform.

Comment: @LL3.14 It is not that I can assume $f,g \in D(V)$ if I only know that $f,g \in D(H)$. It is that I only need the density argument in proving that $\int \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}g = \int f \frac{d^2 g}{dx^2}$. So for the $H$ case, I need the functions of $L^2$ with the Laplacian in $L^2$. So the domain is bigger than $H^2(\mathbb{R})$, and I'm wondering how the density argument applies here. For $P$, the domain is $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ yes.

Comment: @whpowell96 I have found this which answers my question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335952/domain-of-definition-of-laplace-operator-on-l2. But why is $\{u\in L^2: \Delta u \in L^2\}=H^2$? I am not sure why $u, \Delta u\in L^2$ implies $\nabla u \in L^2$.

Comment: On $\mathbb{R}^n$, the Fourier transform is an easy way to argue this. See part 3 of these notes https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/245c-notes-4-sobolev-spaces/

Comment: @whpowell96 I'm sorry but I cannot see how this works. I can see that $W^{k,2}=H^2$, but how does this imply that $u,\Delta u \in L^2$ implies $\nabla u \in L^2$? I don't know what weak derivatives have to do with this?